# Recursive rules in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm very new to Prolog and I'm struggling to understand how exactly recursive rules work.I have the classic example of member/2 predicate which finds if the X variable is a member of a given list:

```
member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]):- member(X,T).
```

What I search for is an explanation of which variable **unifies** with what and with **what order are executed** the clauses.

Obviously the result of a query is like this:

```
?- member(X,[yolanda,trudy,vincent,jules]).
X = yolanda;
X = trudy;
X = vincent;
X = jules;
no
```

Comment: Vertical order (top to bottom), for each call. You can see what's happening using e.g. trace - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Comment: Go ahead and get yourself a copy of "The Art of Prolog". You can download it for free from the publisher's website. You will find textbook-quality explanations of this topic there.

Comment: Only one question: The Head part of the recursive rule...when is it being executed??